# How to get multiple sentences from pastebin.com and put them into a list?

Tags: python

So I have this pastebin link here https://pastebin.com/raw/vxGkayKY And I want a way for python to get the sentence and the response both and put them in a list. Is there any way to do this?
So for example:

```py
list = [
   'This is my first sentence.\nHere\'s a response for it.',
   'Here\'s another sentence.\nHere\'s another response.',
   'Here\'s the third sentence.\nHere\'s another response.'
]
```

I'm trying to make the python code to pick a random sentence using `random.choice(list)`

So for example, the output will be (ignore the #):

```
#This is my first sentence.
#Here's a response for it.
```

Is there any way to do this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
import random

req = requests.get('https://pastebin.com/raw/vxGkayKY')
lines = req.text.strip().replace('\r','').split('\n\n')
choice = random.choice(lines)

print(choice)
```

As a side-note, it's bad style to overwrite keywords like `list` with a variable since you might need them later on.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much :)
(I sent a comment earlier but I don't think I see it, so here's another one)